# MATLAB: anonymous functions 'might be used incompatibly or redefined'

Tags: matlab, function, histogram

I'm getting this error in the third line when doing the following:

```
hist_paramd = @(x) hist(x, -1:0.1:1)
data_cell = num2cell(data)
histograms = cellfun(@hist_paramd,data_cell)
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Edit: changed from original question as it turned out rowfun wasn't even available in my MATLAB version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is almost surely related to the fact that you don't need `@hist_paramd` in the `cellfun`, only `hist_paramd`. This is because `hist_paramd` is already a function handle (being an anonymous function). You only need the `@` when creating handles to named functions (i.e. to functions defined in m-files or built-ins):

```
histograms = cellfun(hist_paramd,data_cell) %anonymous function
%histograms = cellfun(@sin,data_cell) %named function
```

This is easy to understand if you imagine the definition of `hist_paramd` in the cellfun:

```
histograms = cellfun(@(x) hist(x, -1:0.1:1),data_cell);
```

clearly you don't need another `@`.

Comment: Thanks, that's most probably a good half of my mistake. The other mistake I made is not realizing that cellfun cannot deal with vector valued output.

Comment: @JohnSmith: it can. Call it as `histograms = cellfun(@(x) hist(x, -1:0.1:1),data_cell,'uniformoutput',false);`. This will make your output `histograms` be a cell, with each element containing the output vectors.

Comment: Wow, now you fully resolved my issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnSmith no problem:)